# recursion returning unexpected output

Tags: c++, recursion

I am starting with  test(2,8)

I think the output should be   4 7
Instead I am getting 6 6 4 7
since p1 = p2   i.e. 6 = 6 the cout statement should not be performed. 
Why am I seeing the 6 6 ?

```
 using namespace std;

 void test(int p1, int p2);

  void  main()
  {
     test(2, 8);
     return ;
   }


  void  test(int p1, int p2)
  {
   if (p1 != p2)
   {
    p1 = p1 + 2;
    p2 = p2 - 1;
    test(p1, p2);
    cout << p1;
    cout << p2;
   }
  }
```

Comment: 6 6 4 7 is correct , I guess you are not getting the recursive flow of the code

Comment: Your recursive call to `test(p1, p2)` is occurring *before* your `cout << p1` and `count << p2` that you think might be outputting `4 7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first  call to  test  **p1** becomes 4 and **p2** becomes 7. But before printing we again go into recursion , this time **p1** becomes 6 and **p2** also becomes 6. We again call recursion but as **p1** is same as **p2** it returns without printing anything ( does not enter if condition ). Then it prints 6 6 and when it returns to the most above level call to test function it prints 4 7. So output is 6 6 4 7.

Comment: What is confusing me is the cout is in the IF statement, so since 6 = 6 how is the cout being executed?

Comment: @Herbie `4 7` is printed from within the `if ( 2 != 8 )`, and `6 6` is printed from within the `if ( 4 != 7 )`

Comment: as @MattMcNabb said 6,6 is printed when arguments 4 , 7 are passed to test